# What does apply_filters(...) actually do in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, function

I'm trying to understand some of the function in WordPress, but I can't get my head around what [apply_filters(...)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) actually does.

Is someone able to clear this up for me with a few examples?

Comment: Awesome: http://dev.themeblvd.com/tutorial/filters/

Comment: A note that `apply_filters()` is an incredibly misleading name for the function as it applies both filters *and* actions hooked onto the target function

Comment: @NabilKadimi, great suggestion, http://dev.themeblvd.com/tutorial/filters/#highlighter_604585,  but when this function does not accept any arguments(please click the link to see which function I am talking about), how is the $output variable altered , as he describes in his next code section?

Comment: @RameshPareek You're link doesn't seem to work as expected, please use a Github gist.

Comment: sorry! Please scroll down to **Example 1: The Basics** on that page.

Comment: @NabilKadimi Not awesome at all that you broke the rules back then by providing only a link instead of an answer. Now, though the question is still valid (and something I need to know) your answer is useless because the page is gone.

Comment: [Awesome (from Google's cache)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WQaz15gpYXoJ:dev.themeblvd.com/tutorial/filters/&client=ubuntu-sn&sca_esv=556318805&hl=en&gl=ma&strip=1&vwsrc=0)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`apply_filters($tag, $value)` passes the 'value' argument to each of the functions 'hooked' (using [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)) into the specified filter 'tag'. Each function performs some processing on the value and returns a modified value to be passed to the next function in the sequence.

For example, by default (in WordPress 2.9) the [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter passes the value through the following sequence of functions:

- wptexturize
- convert_smilies
- convert_chars
- wpautop
- shortcode_unautop
- prepend_attachment
- do_shortcode

Comment: Also remember to echo anything that you are not using the value of if it seems that `apply_filters($value)` is wiping out a value...

Answer (score 33):

*late answer*

#### Short explanation

[`apply_filters()`](http://queryposts.com/function/apply_filters/) interacts with the `global $wp_filters` array. Basically it just checks the array if the current filter (or hook) has an action(/callback function) attached and then calls it.

#### Long explanation

When you attach a callback/action to a filter or hook, then you just add the callback name to global filters array. When then, in code (for e.g. a template, core or plugin file) a call to `do_action()` or `apply_filters()` happens, then WordPress searched through the array and calls the callback. The only thing more special with filters than with hooks is, that it returns the value (for further handling) instead of just firing the callback. So summed up: Hooks are to *insert* data, while filters are to *modify* data.

Answer (score 20):

Here's what I'm gleaning, upon considering the most popular answer and additional resources:

- $tag seems to be a synonym for the name of the hook. (That's not particularly intuitive to me.)
- the_content is an example of a hook, of the "filter" type.
- the_content hook consists of multiple filters.
- Filters modify data. They basically filter the database, changing the data before the users view it.
- A common use of apply_filters(), for instance, is to apply the_content filters to $content. In this instance, double returns will convert to `<p>` tags, smiley faces will convert to icons, etc.
- "the_content" is a hook, while "the_content()" is a function.

Answer (score 1):

In the most basic terms, apply_filters is used to initialise a filter hook... add_filter assigns a new function to hooks that have already been created.

Comment: Sorry, this is the wrong way around:  apply_filters() calls the filter hooks that are already initialized and add_filter() is the call that creates a filter hook.  I know you actually meant this, but you have the functions around the wrong way!

Comment: apply_filters($tag,$value); allows you to create a place in your code where you can then allow the $value you pass to be hooked into and modified by using add_filter();