# Differences Between plugins_url('aaa.php') and plugins_url('aaa.php', dirname(__FILE__)) in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to know if there are differences in these two different usage of [plugin_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url). They both produce the same string.

```
echo plugins_url('aaa.php')

echo plugins_url('aaa.php', dirname(__FILE__));
```

When is one used and the other not?

Thanks.

Comment: You can look-up any of these functions in Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url - If you can not find enough information in there, you can always read the source-code of it.

Comment: @hakre The link does not tell the differences.

Comment: The link that explains the *exact* difference is here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2022

Comment: @hakre If you think so, you can put it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @hakre Added the codex link. What do you think about this question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270989/what-does-apply-filters-actually-do-in-wordpress What you don't like the question does not mean it's not worthy for future users.

Comment: in the interests of shorter code, it's worth pointing out that if you're using PHP 5.3 or higher (which you should be!), you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo plugins_url('aaa.php')`

--> This is used for normal wordpress

`echo plugins_url('aaa.php', dirname(__FILE__));`

--> This is used for Multi network

**if you define `dirname(__FILE__)` in plugins_url function**

then it takes **Wordpress Multi Network Plugins url**

otherwise it takes **Direct Wordpress Plugin url**

Comment: Do you mean [WordPress MU](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_MU#WordPress_MU_Support_and_Installation) by Muti network? Indeed the source code indicates `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WP_PLUGIN_URL`.  So if the muti-site feature is enabled, does `plugins_url('aaa.php', dirname(__FILE__))` produce a different value?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I may try the MU plugin to see what happens.