# What does apply_filters do?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a  scenario like this , since its  a big code, I'm asking this in an easy way:

In a file called `One.php`, I have something like this:

```
add_filter('eshopaddtocheckout','eshop_extras_checkout');

function eshop_extras_checkout($echo){
    //blah blah..   
}
```

In a file, `Two.php`, I have something like this:

```
$echo = apply_filters('eshopaddtocheckout',$echo);
```

My doubts are:

1. I don't understood how `Two.php` made a connection with the `One.php` file? I didnt even find a line using something like `include One.php` inside the `Two.php` file  (BUT the functionality is working perfectly between the 2 files)
2. what does apply_filters do?

Answer (score 7):

There is no php function `apply_filters`.  It must be defined by some additional software you are using; perhaps wordpress?  If so, there's an answer here that may help: [What does apply_filters(...) actually do in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270989/what-does-apply-filters-actually-do-in-wordpress)

Comment: @david - Jules already answered your doubts and queries by referring you to the link in his answer where everything is explained. apply_filter() is internal wordpress function that passes arguments to hooked functions. this is how the "connection" is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can register filters with WordPress, passing a name and a function to `add_filter`. These can contain actions you want to perform on some data before it is used. `apply_filters` calls these with arguments, `$echo` in your example.

See the [WordPress documentation on filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, there is no PHP function called apply_filters nor do_action.  These are Wordpress event driven hooks; specifically made for extensions.

For a better understanding, please refer to:  https://wpshout.com/apply_filters-do_action/

Hope this helps.