# Retrieving JSON data that is saved as text in mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a form with number of elments, I encode all the data from the form using json_encode($_POST) and save it to mysql data base.

This is the JSON data i have in mysql database

```
{"sections":{"int":{"section_name":"Interests","data":"These are my interests"},"ref":{"section_name":"Referance","data":"This Is my referance"},"other":{"section_name":"other","data":"This Is my referance"}}}
```

The JSON data saved to mysql is wellformed. I copy/paste the data from mysql database to jsoneditoronline dot org and checked for errors. The JSON data has no errors at all.

Now when i retrieve the same JSON data using mysql queries,

The start double quote in the JSON is being replaced by “ 
End double quote is being replaced by ”

So i can't use the JSON data. How can i get exact JSON data from mysql table?

I am using wordpress inbuilt functions to retrive the JSON data

```
$id=366; 
$post = get_page($id);
$JSON = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $JSON;
```

The $JSON should have valid JSON according to the data stored in mysql database, but it is being replaced by html special characters automatically.

How to over come this?

How to get valid JSON from mysql database through mysql query?

Comment: But isn't the problem that you in fact are using `apply_filters()` and the `the_content()` filter function is modifying the data from the database? Would this work: `$json = json_encode($post->post_content); echo $json;`

Comment: [What does apply_filters(…) actually do in WordPress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270989/what-does-apply-filters-actually-do-in-wordpress)

Comment: @KristerAndersson is it `json_decode`?

Comment: @Krister Post_content is already Json encoded using PHP. If tried json_encode again, Str_replace &# 8221; to " It's not working. There should be some way to make this work

Comment: I guess this is not going to be easy to retrieve VALID JSON using inbuilt wordpress functions. Valid JSON is retrieved when i use custom mysql queries inside wordpress. However i saved valid JSON to post_content using wp_insert_post() inbuilt wordpress function. If saving is possible, retrieving should also be possible... I will get back if i find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

html_entity_decode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)
or
urldecode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

may help.

Comment: No, html entity decode some how replaces the special character to a special double quote, but this double quote is not providing valid JSON.

Comment: Can you write that bad formed JSON?

Comment: {“sections”:{“int”:{“section_name”:”Interests”,”data”:”These are my interests”},”ref”:{“section_name”:”Referance”,”data”:”This Is my referance”},”other”:{“section_name”:”other”,”data”:”This Is my referance”}}}

Comment: the quotes are the only problem. It is getting replaced with some special characters

Comment: Sorry about late answer. This might solve the problem in the ugly way.
`$str = "{“sections”:{“int”:{“section_name”:”Interests”,”data”:”These are my interests”},”ref”:{“section_name”:”Referance”,”data”:”This Is my referance”},”other”:{“section_name”:”other”,”data”:”This Is my referance”}}}";

$str = str_replace(["“", "”"], "\"", $str); `

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode($jsonarray, JSON_UNSCAPED_SLASHES);

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.